# Where does the AfD stand on rental price freezes?

Tags: economy, parties, germany, housing

It [seems](https://www.tellerreport.com/news/2019-06-14---also-spd-for-this--rent-freezing-nationwide---idea-heats-housing-debate-.HkgkkdEZyB.html) to me that the SPD is largely in favor of such measures (rental price freezes) while the CDU generally opposes them.

Does the AfD have an identifiable position on this matter? (I think this is an  interesting question because right-wing populist/radical parties [generally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSwVU.png) aren't very right-wing on economics matters, particularly on state intervention in the economy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AfD is [opposed](https://afdkompakt.de/2019/11/26/der-berliner-mietendeckel-ruiniert-den-wohnungsbau/) to the freeze (link goes to a website of the right-wing extremist AfD) because it thinks that it will hinder investments.

See also [here](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/umstrittenes-mietengesetz-in-berlin-afd-im-bundestag-will-verfassungsrechtlich-gegen-mietendeckel-vorgehen/25541050.html) for the actions they want to take and potential conflicts of interest in the matter.

Comment: A bit surprising I have to say. I would have expected them to be a bit more split on the matter, internally. Given how they've phrased that response it seems that they're most concerned with slamming the "red-greens", perhaps because they compete with them (more) intensely in the East.

Comment: @Fizz In my experience, right-wing extremist parties are also right wing in economic matters (at least in action, less so in rhetoric). The AfD specifically has been [classified](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_f%C3%BCr_Deutschland#Europa-,_Finanz-_und_Wirtschaftspolitik) as market-fundamentalist and national-liberal (liberal regarding markets, not social policies). The national socialist wing of the party is [a bit more populist](https://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2020-02/afd-wirtschaftspolitik-volkspartei-sozialstaat-umverteilung-rentenkonzept/komplettansicht) in its rhetoric though.

Comment: I see. I guess this one aspect on which they diverge from France's FN (now NR).

Comment: If you look at the origins of the party, they were founded as an radical economic liberal party. This still defines their political positions in economics, even though they're now right wing populist.